# How to smooth only curves while leaving corners intact?

Tags: modeling, geometry, smooth

Possibly a very basic question, but I haven't found information on how to do this in the user manual…

I have a relatively complex object which features both curves and sharp corners but, to make this example easier, consider a cylinder. If I want to make the round face of the cylinder even rounder (add vertices) but not affect the the flatness of the two circular faces, in such a way that the cylinder does not become a capsule, what should I do? Up to now, my few attempts to following tutorials on how to smooth objects has resulted in all the flat faces of my model getting curved, which is not what I want. I just want the faces which are *already* curves to be even rounder.

Now here's my reasoning (correct me if I'm wrong, which might very well be the case): Curves do not really exist in Blender, as far as I know, so everything that looks round in an object is only an estimation, made of rectangular or triangular planes. So, to do what I want to achieve, I'd have to tell Blender what a curve is, that is, what angle between two planes should be treated as round, and what angle should be treated as a corner. Am I on the right path here, or am I completely misunderstanding everything?

Comment: You should take a closer look at the *Geometry Nodes*. You can use them to create a cylinder, for example, and subsequently influence/increase the accuracy you mentioned. And of course: Blender knows curves, and what you mean is called "Resolution" in the case of curves or *Geometry Nodes*.

Comment: If you plan to add edges along your cylinder and make some parts rounder and some not, you can use a Shrinkwrap modifier with a cylinder as Target and with a vertex group so that only the vertex group will stick to the Target, is it what you want?

Comment: @quellenform Thank you for your response. Before I start investing time into this, is this something that I could do in bulk, rather than working every part of my model individually? Here's the specific object I have: https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/97c5/plb3bnrzw0tbhbj9g.jpg If you take a look, you can see that there are many different curved parts…

Comment: @quellenform …Eventually, I want to be able to work with models which are even more complex than this, so I' don't want to have to treat each curve individually. By the way, in case it matters, I'm importing these LEGO® parts as STL and DAE (COLLADA) files, not creating them in Blender directly.

Comment: @moonboots Thank you for your response. This sounds very interesting, but seems like the type of operation that needs to be conducted for every part of the model individually, and cannot be done in bulk, using curve detection. What I'm rather looking for is something that will automatically optimise *all* the curves in my model without affecting the flat parts.